# Ionic app 4 data not loaded on other devices

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm building ionic apps with angular 8. i have tested it on my device everything works just fine. But when my collages and client install it, the datas like image and text from json not showing up.
[image: heres the screenshot from my device]

[image: heres from my client devices]

did anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: once check URL your using. is it pointing to image correctly? also in new security update android allow `https://` URL calling only.

Comment: it is using https and pointing perfectly